# Equivalent of SQLite3 each() function in PostgreSQL Node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, sqlite

So I'm converting from database in a Node.js app from SQLite3 to PostgreSQL. Originally, I had my database equal to something like:

```
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./dbName.db', (err) => {
   if (err) {
     return console.error(err.message);
   }
   console.log("Connected to database");
});
```

I was able to call db.each() on it when I wanted to query data from the table. In PostgreSQL, I'm setting up the database with:

```
const db = new Client({
  user: 'myName',
  host: 'hostName',
  database: 'databaseName',
  password: 'password',
  port: ####,
});
```

My query code for the original implementation (SQLite3) was part of an async function request:

```
function featureArrayHelper() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let featureArray = []
    let passedInVar = passedInVarValue

    db.each('SELECT rowid,* FROM table WHERE var4 > (?)', [passedInVar], (err, row) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      } else {
        let jsonObject = {
          var1: row.var1,
          var2 : row.var2,
          var3 : row.var3,
          var4 : row.var4,
          var5: 0
      }
      featureArray.push(jsonObject)
    }
  }, (err, n) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err)
    } else {
      resolve(featureArray)
    }
  });
})
}
```

where the actual post request was:

```
app.post('/', async function(request, response) {
  const featureArray = await featureArrayHelper()
  response.send(JSON.stringify(featureArray))
});
```

In this implementation, when I try to deploy the Node app to Heroku, I get an error on a line where I try to call db.each(), so what can I replace it with to retain the functionality established in the SQLite3 version?

Comment: Can you provide the relevant query code and what you tried for the new postgres API? What library are you using for postgres and what do their API docs say? Have you tried something generic like [knex](https://knexjs.org/) so you can port more easily?

Comment: @Matt I put the query code in the question. Honestly, I'm new to PostgreSQL so I'm not even sure my server setup is correct yet, but this is just a syntactical issue and I'm sure I'll figure out if it's set up correctly once this is resolved. What do you mean by 'port more easily'?

Comment: "port" is a term used for what you are doing, moving code from one system to another without changing much functionality.

Answer (score 1):

[Postgres `pg`](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries) uses [`client.query`](https://node-postgres.com/api/client#clientquery) and doesn't provide a built in function to loop through rows. Javascript provides multiple ways to handle arrays, for example `rows.map()` returns a new, modified array or `rows.each()` will work the same as the posted code.

```
async function featureArrayHelper() {
  let var4 = value4 // not sure what this was for, maybe `passedInVar`?

  const query = { 
    text: 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE var4 > $1',
    values: [ passedInVar ],
  }
  const res = await db.query(query)
  return res.rows.map(row => {
    return {
      var1: row.var1,
      var2: row.var2,
      var3: row.var3,
      var4: row.var4,
      var5: 0
    }
  })
}
```

[Knex](https://knexjs.org/#Installation-client) is a query builder, designed to sit atop multiple types of database so you don't have to go through as much to change databases ("porting"). The query/code is the same for both sqlite and postgres, only the connection setup differs.

```
async function featureArrayHelper(passedInVar) {
  const rows = await knex.select('*')
     .from('table')
     .where({ var4: passedInVar })
  return rows.map(row => {
    return {
      var1: row.var1,
      var2: row.var2,
      var3: row.var3,
      var4: row.var4,
      var5: 0
    }
  })
}
```

For more advanced queries you will likely end up with some database specifics, but knex will cover up a lot of those differences.

Comment: Hi Matt, sorry I wasn't more specific--the featureArrayHelper() function is the function that is called with the await, and it's contained in a larger POST async function, I'm having a bit of trouble converting your code into my current set up--how would I modify it to make it work?

Comment: I also edited the original question to include the relevant code :-) Thank you